# startActivityForResult is deprecated, I'm trying to update my code

Tags: java, android, deprecated, deprecation-warning

i'm new to android. just trying to make a webview app instead of an actual mobile app, then i'll use my flask app as a mobile app.

the app works fine as it is, no problems at all but startActivityForResult is giving me a warning.
here's the code:

```
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
        String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

        //checking for storage permission to write images for upload
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, perms, FCR);

            //checking for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission
        } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, FCR);

            //checking for CAMERA permissions
        } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, FCR);
        }
        if (mUMA != null) {
            mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mUMA = filePathCallback;
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            } else {
                takePictureIntent = null;
            }
        }
        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
        if (multiple_files) {
            contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        }
        Intent[] intentArray;
        if (takePictureIntent != null) {
            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
        } else {
            intentArray = new Intent[0];
        }

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);

        return true;
    }
```

here's onActivityResult i still couldn't make it work...

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    Uri[] results = null;
    if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == FCR){
            if(null == mUMA){
                return;
            }
            if(intent == null || intent.getData() == null){
                if(mCM != null){
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                }
            }else{
                String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                if(dataString != null){
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                } else {
                    if(multiple_files) {
                        if (intent.getClipData() != null) {
                            final int numSelectedFiles = intent.getClipData().getItemCount();
                            results = new Uri[numSelectedFiles];
                            for (int i = 0; i < numSelectedFiles; i++) {
                                results[i] = intent.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
    mUMA = null;
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Replace `startActivityForResult` with Callback for for Activity Result

```
Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
startActivityIntent.launch(chooserIntent);
```

Callback for for Activity Result - `startActivityIntent`

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startActivityIntent = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
               // Add same code that you want to add in onActivityResult method
            }
        });
```

For more info check [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#java).

Comment: okay, after trying a bit more i managed to make it work. thanks again.

Comment: It is giving error "Unable to find intent" with my intent details. Where to place the ActivityResultLauncher?

Comment: how do you put the request code intent??