# how to get a variable in an activity from another activity and make the main activity to use variable after initializing from there ?(kotlin )

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

my kotlin project has 2 activitis (main , second called : AddPlayer)
main activity has a button called "Add a player" that it starts second activity .
in second activity i have 2 edit text to get a number and a text from user .
after press submit button in second activity , in the main activity i want add these values to my mutablelist
but idk how to do it
( i think it crashed because main activity uses those variables before getting values from user)
plz guide me .

my activity code :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var enteredPlayerNumber = 0
 private var enteredPlayerName: String=""

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val myRecyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
    val myViewModel = ViewModel()
    val btnAdd = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnAdd)



    myRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    myViewModel.getUserData()
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener {
        val myIntent = Intent(this, AddPlayerActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(myIntent)
    }




    myViewModel.myList.observe(this) {
        myRecyclerView.adapter = MyAdapter(it)
    }


}}
```

and my second activity :

```
class AddPlayerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_player)

    val numberAddPlayer = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etNumberAdd2)
    val nameAddPlayer = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etNameAdd2)

    val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnSubmitAdd2)



    btn.setOnClickListener {
        val myIntent=Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        myIntent.putExtra("USERNAME", nameAddPlayer.text)
        myIntent.putExtra("USER_NUMBER", numberAddPlayer.text)
        startActivity(myIntent)

    }

}}
```

Comment: startActivityForResult... Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71082372/startactivityforresult-is-deprecated-im-trying-to-update-my-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pull data out of an `Intent` that was used to start an `Activity`, just do this in your `onCreate`:

```
intent?.run {
    val userName = getStringExtra("USERNAME")
    val userNumber = getStringExtra("USER_NUMBER")

    if (username != null && userNumber != null {
        // do whatever with that data
    }
}
```

You need to null-check because those values might not be present, e.g. if `MainActivity` was started by launching the app, not by the button being clicked in `AddPlayerActivity`.

Also, if you click the button and get back to `MainActivity`, and put the app in the background and it gets destroyed, when it's recreated `onCreate` will run again, see the same `intent` (the last one is preserved when it's recreating the state) and it'll pull the values and do the thing with them again. If that means adding something to a list, you might get duplicates

One way to avoid that is check if `savedInstanceState` is *null* - if it is, you're coming into the activity fresh, so it's ok to check the intent. If it's not *null*, then you're recreating some saved state from an already-open activity, so you don't want to repeat the check

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // do the intent stuff
    }
```

but that might depend on what you're doing with your activities and the task backstack - test it to make sure it's doing what you expect!

---

The recommended approach by the Android devs at this point is a *single-activity architecture* where instead of an `Activity` for each screen, you have just one, and use `Fragment`s for your screens and swap them in and out instead.

A lot of the *Jetpack* components are designed around this idea, including the *Navigation* library, and *ViewModels* which allow the `Fragments` that share an `Activity` to also share a central store of data and react to changes.

Looks like you're already using a `ViewModel`, but by sharing an Activity you'd be able to have your `AddPlayer` fragment do something like `model.addUser(name, number)`. The model could store that new user if you want (e.g. in a database, or SharedPreferences or whatever) and update the data it's making visible. `MainFragment` could `observe` that data and update its display as necessary

Doing things that way is a lot easier to reason about, you don't need to worry about Activity states etc (part of the reason for creating `ViewModel` is so a lot of that work is taken care of for you) and it's a more modern way to write Android apps. Might be worth looking into!

Comment: thank you , excuse me i have a question , i added (  intent?.run ) part into my code , it woked just for one time and each time i wanna add a player again , it is replaced the previous one , how can i solve it ?

Comment: @M.hosseinKarimi when the Activity is first created (so it runs `onCreate`) you're checking if the `Intent` used to start the activity has your piece of data in it. Basically, you're checking if you just came from `AddPlayerActivity`, which only sends over one piece of data. If you want to take that data and add it to some collection you're building up, you'll need a way to store that collection, load it when the Activity starts, and add any new data that's in the `Intent`. Persisting data is a big topic - here's the Android docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/

Comment: specially tnx to you